# jQuery matching ID with a ' = ' in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

Has anyone tried matching an id with an equal sign (=) in it, and WORKED?  E.g.:

```
// DOM structure
/*DOC += <span id='Test=Test' class='something'></span> */
var test = $('#Test=Test');
```

I tried the above code.  jQuery doesn't like it and returned undefined.  However if I match the span's class, I could actually find the span (and subsequently query the value of id).

If I have to match the id with '=' in it, are there any ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: try escaping it? `("#Test\\=Test");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, at first I want to notice that the equal sign is not a valid character for the [ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id), it can still be used, but you might have unexpected behavior between different browsers.

> > ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

About jQuery, the `=` character on selectors must be escaped by a double back-slash:

```
$('#Test\\=Test');
```

More info:

- [Special characters in selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors#Special_characters_in_selectors)

The full list of characters that need to be escaped: `#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/`

Comment: As you say, the equal sign is not valid in an ID attribute, so why are you saying it can still be used?

Comment: Cause you can. But should not.
You can use it at your own risk.

Comment: If you use an ID with an equal sign, your document will not be valid HTML, meaning all bets are off as to whether a user agent will even render it. Even if it does (as all the major browsers will), all ID-related behaviour (e.g. CSS selectors, document.getElementById, URL hashes) will have undefined behaviour (and here I would bet there will be variations in browser behaviour). Why even consider risking it?